# Disable Visual Studio 2010 Html Tag Pair Editing

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

Ok so this should be simple. How do you make visual studio 2010 not modify the other part of an HTML tag-pair? I know there were a bunch of settings to hit for previous versions of Visual Studio to disable before. But this *feature* is destroying my html when VS can't parse it properly.

Comment: Apparently this feature is by design. Just leaving this up here for future people who are stymied by VS2010

Comment: This used to work for me, but no longer does. I would actually like to turn it on, but can't find the setting anywhere! Edit: This may be a resharper thing. I recently uninstalled it, and that may be why I don't have the feature anymore. Are you using resharper?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you are searching for:

- Tools
- Options
- Text Editor
- HTML
- Formatting
- Uncheck the box for **Auto insert close tag**

Comment: No that's not the one. The behavior I don't want is as follows: I have a pair of div tags, and I try and delete the closing tag. I end up with a < class="whatever"> as my start tag. VS2010 can't seem to match up the HTML correctly, so this is very annoying.

Comment: I can't really recreate this behavior. If I have a `<div id="foo"></div>` tag and delete the `</div>` closing tag, I end up with `<div id="foo">`. Do you have any additional extension installed?

Comment: I used an incorrect choice of words. Try to delete the text div but leave the <> alone.
It is fine when VS can match up HTML tags properly. It's utterly disastrous when it doesn't match it properly and breaks the page.

Comment: These days it's under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Advanced under the Completion section (Auto insert closing tag)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I was searching for the same thing in 2020. The setting to turn this off/on can be found via the following steps:

1. User Settings
2. Extensions
3. HTML
4. Mirror Cursor on Matching Tag.

Hope this might actually help someone. This stuff destroyed my productivity when writing HTML.

Comment: This looks like it is for VS Code, not Visual Studio