# Prevent self closing html tags in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I'm learning ASP.NET Web Forms and I'm wondering if it's possible to prevent self closing tags when the html code is generated. For instance, if I create an input element, it will self close. How can I prevent this?

Here is the code I'm referring to:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Thank you!

Edit: I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and this is what I found:

- Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced > XHTML coding style

  - change from *True* to *False*

And then:

- Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML (Web Forms) > Formatting > Tag Specific Options > Default Settings > Client tag does not support contents > Closing tag

  - change from *Self-closing tag* to *No closing tag*

However, `<asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>` still gives me `<input type="text" />` in the compiled HTML5 code. The result I want is `<input type="text">`.

So if anyone knows how to accomplish this, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Why? Self-closing tags are perfectly valid tags 2) You can write any kind of tag you want in the aspx file. Are you referring to some control-generated tags? Did you check the various templated controls? Some actual code would help

Comment: 1. Because I write my html5 code without self closing tags and I don't want any.
2. I've edited the op.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110446/disable-visual-studio-2010-html-tag-pair-editing) link. Surely want you need is to

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Text Editor
4. HTML
5. Formatting
6. Uncheck the box for **Auto insert close tag**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you can go to :

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > Tag Specific Options

In here you can change the Default Setting of Client and Server tags to be `Seperate` / `Self-Closing`.

You can also change it for specific elements, i.e. `<img>` tags by Finding the `img` item under `Client HTML Tags`

Comment: Thank you! I don't have access to VS right now, but this seems to be it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, you can go to :

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced  > XHTML Coding Style - False